# Java unit test parameterization array

Tags: java, arrays, junit, quicksort, parameterized

Hi I am doing a unit test for QuickSort algorithm (ie sort random numbers in random number to ascending order). However I could not declare a array of numbers in Collection. Could you help. Thank you. 
Also there is syntax error in this line

> this.arrayIn[]= arrayIn;

Am I testing this correctly

> assertEquals(arrayOut, QuickSort.sort(arrayIn));

```
package week8;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class QuickSortTest {

private int[] arrayIn[];
private int length;
private int[] arrayOut[];

public QuickSortTest(int[] arrayIn, int length, int[] arrayOut) {
    this.arrayIn[]= arrayIn;
    this.length=length;
    this.arrayOut[]=arrayOut;   
}

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> parameters(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
        {{1,4,6,3,5,4},6,{1,3,4,4,5,6}}
    });
}
@Test
public void test_quicksort() {
    assertEquals(arrayOut, QuickSort.sort(arrayIn));
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip on assertArrayEquals - was getting gibberish characters when i used assertEquals. 
Thanks for the declaration too! It works now!
Yes i was going to add more parameters but since i'm still getting error for the 1st case, i just stopped to check. I have revised my code as below.

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> parameters(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
        {new int[] {1,4,1,6,3,5}, 6, new int[] {1,1,3,4,5,6}},
        {new int[] {1,4,1,6,3,5}, 6, new int[] {1,3,1,4,5,6}},
        {new int[] {70000,4,1,6,3,5}, 7, new int[] {1,3,4,5,6,70000}},
    });
}

@Test
public void test_quicksort() {
   new QuickSort().sort(arrayIn);
   assertArrayEquals(arrayOut, arrayIn);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of private attribute `arrayIn`:

```
private int[] arrayIn[];
```

is equivalent to:

```
private int[][] arrayIn;
```

So when assigning a value to it, you should do:

```
this.arrayIn = ...; // without the brackets []
```

I don't understand why you're using the parameterized test. Parameterized test is useful for testing multiple input set. And you've only one input set: an in-array and a length. So for instance, using one test method is enough. And make sure you use the right assert method: `assertEquals(Object, Object)` is not adapted here, you should use [`assertArrayEquals(int[], int[])`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(int[],%20int[])):

```
public class QuickSortTest {

    @Test
    public void test_quicksort() {
        ...
        assertArrayEquals(expectedArr, actualArr);
    }
}
```